# Getting jsfiddle 'show image file' working

Tags: image, jsfiddle, preview

I've sure I'm missing something simple here, I found a suggestion on here to use jsfiddle for code to preview an image before upload: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/5234/

But I can't get it to work.  I'm assuming I just put the javascript in the header wrapped in  tags?

Here's my code (thank you - I'm sorry if this is very similar to other questions)

```js
 <script language="javascript">
  window.onload=function readURL(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function (e) {
     $('#artworkshow').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
  }
  
  $("#artwork").change(function(){
   readURL(this);
  });
 </script>
```

```html
    <img id="artworkshow" src="#" alt="Image Preview" />
    <p>
     <label for="artwork">Artwork</label>
     <input id="artwork" name="artwork" type="file" class="inputAuto" />
     Size: 700px by 260px</p>
    <p>
```

Comment: I just tried the JSFiddle and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this, I know the jsfiddle works but I can't get it to work on my page.  I thought it was as easy as putting the script in the header and hey presto but it wasn't.

Comment: Open up the console and see if there are any errors. On IE11 just push F12. The same on Firefox if you have Firebug installed.

Comment: Not sure how to explain this markbernard - it works in jsfiddle but not in my page with identical code putting the js in <script> tags

Comment: I understand but most browsers have an output console. It may show an error that you didn't think was happening. Another option is to host the file that is not working somewhere that I can have a look.

Comment: I've stripped out the rest of the page, tested again incase there was something conflicting it but still no joy.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript">
  function readURL(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
     $('#artworkshow').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
  }
  $("#artwork").change(function(){
   readURL(this);
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
   <img id="artworkshow" src="#" alt="Image Preview" />
   <p>
    <input id="artwork" name="artwork" type="file" class="inputAuto" /></p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Erg that didn't work! If i answer my question does that close it?

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept the answer to indicate that you have found the answer.